# remove headers on pages where there is a sidewaysfigure

Tags: header-footer, rotating

I have a Latex document with headers on each page.

On the pages where I have a 'sidewaysfigure', I want to remove the headers, because sometimes, the white borders of the large sideways figures overlap the header.

Is it possible to remove headers on pages where there are sidewaysfigures?

---

Edit -

So here is my minimal working example. I have a main file which calls the other files - sorry I don't know the correct terminology. It's called testlatex.tex. It calls a file called test.tex which has the sideways figure.

I have
    \thispagestyle{empty}
in the sidewaysfigure environment, but the header and footer still appear.

testlatex.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{ociamthesis}  % default square logo 

\usepackage[bottom=37mm,top=10mm,left=33mm,right=33mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fourier} % The Fourier font package.
\usepackage{microtype} % Apparently this makes pdfs look nicer.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}
\include{mymacros}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\title{Test title}
\abstracttitle{}
\author{a.n.other}             %your name
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{13}{8}{10}  % For size 12 text 
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt % this looks about double-line
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newgeometry{bottom=4cm,top=4cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm}
\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt
\doublespacing
\include{test} 
\end{document}
```

Test.tex

```
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PNG/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PDF/}   {Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/EPS/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
\fi

\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[ width=200mm]{anything.png}
\caption[]{Figure caption here.}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: But where would I put that in the tex document to ensure that it was acting on the same page as the figure will appear?

Comment: Within the `sidewaysfigure` environment.

Comment: That didn't seem to remove the header.

Comment: If it really didn't we need to see a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: minimal working example provided :)

Comment: I have seen so, but it doesn't show the behaviour you are describing in the comment to esdds answer.

Comment: When I run this code, I see a page with a sideways figure - and that page also includes the header and footer. You suggested that \thispagestyle{empty} would remove the header and footer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25234/discussion-between-user1551817-and-johannes-b).

Answer (score 3):

With package [floatpag](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatpag) you could use `\rotfloatpagestyle{<pagestyle>}`

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{floatpag}
\rotfloatpagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blindtext
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\fbox{\parbox[c][.5\textwidth][c]{.5\textwidth}{\centering\Huge Figure}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also the command `\thisfloatpagestyle{<pageststyle>}` that can be used inside the float environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{floatpag}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blindtext
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
\centering
\fbox{\parbox[c][.5\textwidth][c]{.5\textwidth}{\centering\Huge Figure}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This almost worked perfectly, but on the pages where I have non-sideways figures (and no text), the header remains (which is fine) but the underline of the header and the page number footer disappear.

Comment: Actually the page number moves to the top right of the page.