# remove header and footer from sideways figure page

Tags: header-footer

I have a latex 'control' file that calls another file.

The control file produces a header and footer on each page.

There are some pages with a sidewaysfigure, that I wish to remove the header and footer from.

I was advised that I could do this using \thispagestyle{empty} in the sidewaysfigure environment, but the header and footer still appear.

Below are my files which give a minimum working example:

Control file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{ociamthesis}  % default square logo 

\usepackage[bottom=37mm,top=10mm,left=33mm,right=33mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fourier} % The Fourier font package.
\usepackage{microtype} % Apparently this makes pdfs look nicer.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}
\include{mymacros}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\title{Test title}
\abstracttitle{}
\author{a.n.other}             %your name
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{13}{8}{10}  % For size 12 text 
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt % this looks about double-line
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newgeometry{bottom=4cm,top=4cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm}
\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt
\doublespacing
\include{test} 
\end{document}
```

File with figure:

```
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PNG/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PDF/}   {Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/EPS/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
\fi

\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[ width=200mm]{anything.png}
\caption[]{Figure caption here.}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

Comment: In which way is that question different from [remove headers on pages where there is a sidewaysfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252140)?

Comment: I added the working example to that to as an edit, but I wasn't sure if anyone would see that post now it's a few days old. So I posted a new question.

Comment: As soon as you edit a question, it is put back on top of the main page.